# docker-compose flask container site can't be reached linux | simple flask site

Tags: linux, docker, flask, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm new to Docker and i'm trying Using docker-compose to run two flask containers that will return Hello- World, but listening on different ports.
but I can't reach the site

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7
COPY app.py /app/
WORKDIR /app/
RUN pip3 install Flask
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
        return "Hello-World"
if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  flask1:
    image: imgflask
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
  flask2:
    image: imgflask
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5001:5000"
```

imgflask:

> sudo docker build -t imgflask .

I used `sudo docker-compose up` to run containers

```
Recreating flaskapp_flask1_1
Recreating flaskapp_flask2_1
Attaching to flaskapp_flask1_1, flaskapp_flask2_1
flask1_1  |  * Serving Flask app 'app'
flask1_1  |  * Debug mode: on
flask1_1  | WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
flask1_1  |  * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
flask1_1  |  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
flask1_1  |  * Running on http://172.19.0.2:5000
flask1_1  | Press CTRL+C to quit
flask1_1  |  * Restarting with stat
flask2_1  |  * Serving Flask app 'app'
flask2_1  |  * Debug mode: on
flask2_1  | WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
flask2_1  |  * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
flask2_1  |  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
flask2_1  |  * Running on http://172.19.0.3:5000
flask2_1  | Press CTRL+C to quit
flask2_1  |  * Restarting with stat
flask1_1  |  * Debugger is active!
flask1_1  |  * Debugger PIN: 134-785-807
flask2_1  |  * Debugger is active!
flask2_1  |  * Debugger PIN: 850-320-821
```

but the I tried `http://127.0.0.1:5000` `http://172.19.0.2:5000` `http://localhost:5000` but no success
"This site can’t be reached", how can i fix this.

Comment: First, thank you providing all the bits necessary to run your code; many first time posters neglect to provide all the pieces necessary to reproduce the problem they're asking about. Unfortunately, everything here looks fine, and when I run it locally ports 5000 and 5001 are exposed on my host as expected. Can you tell us more about the environment in which you're running this? Is it Windows/Linux (Which?)/MacOS?

Comment: thank you for responding, I have a Windows 10 Home (version 22H2) using a Linux ubuntu (version 20.04.5 LTS (Focal Fossa)) virtual machine

Comment: When you are trying to connect to `http://127.0.0.1:5000`, how are you doing so? That would only work *on the Linux VM running Docker*. From your Windows host, you should be able to connect to `http://<the address of the virtual machine>:5000`.

Comment: it WORKED!!!, thank you .  could you maybe explain to me why did it worked with the VM address?

Comment: You need to use the VM address because that's where you're running Docker, and that's where you've published the port. Your Windows host can't access addresses (like `127.0.0.1` or `172.19.03`) that are internal to the virtual machine.